# What does "go" mean in "the average person that goes and exercises"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *the average person that goes* mean in the following quote [from CNN News](http://www.cnn.com/2016/08/26/politics/donald-trump-doctor-note/)?

> Asked about Trump's health, Bornstein told NBC: "I don't think he's in any better or worse (shape) than the average person that **goes** and exercises every single day," he said. "Doesn't smoke, doesn't drink -- and that's simply the best advantage you can have to live -- and he's got a good family history."

Comment: To "go and exercise" is a single action meaning about the same as "to exercise".

Comment: According to [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+and), '[The] phrase [*go and*] is an intensifier, that is, it heightens the action indicated by the verb that follows it.  For example, *Don't go and eat all the leftover chicken* is stronger than "Don't eat all the leftover chicken."   ...   Sometimes the *and* is omitted, as in *Go tell Dad dinner is ready*, ...'

Comment: I would interpret that as 'taking the time to exercise (for the specific purpose of exercise)'.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Combining the useful comments by [DJClayworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345402/what-does-go-mean-in-the-average-person-that-goes-and-exercises#comment798963_345402) and [Scott](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345402/what-does-go-mean-in-the-average-person-that-goes-and-exercises#comment799092_345402) into an answer, since comments are ephemeral.*</sub>

> To "go and exercise" is a single action meaning about the same as "to exercise".

**Go and** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+and)

> This phrase is an intensifier, that is, it heightens the action indicated by the verb that follows it.
>
> For example, *"Don't go and eat all the leftover chicken"* is stronger than *"Don't eat all the leftover chicken."* ...
>
> Sometimes the *and* is omitted, as in *"Go tell Dad dinner is ready"*, or *"Go fly a kite"*, colloquial imperatives telling someone to do something.

Comment: It needs pointing out that the two answers show different usages, and it's DJClayworth's (not the intensifier) that applies here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see. Can you [edit] this answer to make it better? :)

Comment: If I were doing a real treatment on it, I'd have to mention the related phase constructions (as Collins Cobuild calls them) (and which DJClayworth's 'single action' overlaps to a fair degree)  like 'go shopping', 'go fishing', 'go walking'. But these phase 'go + ing-form' usages do carry the sense of going [out?] somewhere to do whatever it is. In the 'go and infinitive' usage here, I'd say there's less of the 'going out to ...' thrust, but still a little. The emphatic usage is far more common (He's [only] going to go and resign!), as is the sequential usage (I'll go [there] and see).

Comment: The reason why I didn't post this as an answer is that I didn't want to have to defend it. I believe that the "chicken" example uses (at least) approximately the same meaning as the "exercise" quote. And the omission of the "and" is idiomatic. But I'm concerned that the last two examples are really only words being used together: "Go [to where Dad is, or at least a place from which he can hear your voice] ***and*** then tell him dinner is ready," and "Go [to a place outside (where the wind reaches you) and that has enough open space that you can run around] ***and*** fly a kite.